# angular-socket.io 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I have been working on `angular-socket.io`, the server is listening to my designated port. My client keeps getting this ERROR:

> index.js:83 GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MQbYctx 404 (Not Found)

this is what I have so far.

[image: This is my serverside js]

[image: This is the Angular Controller]

[image: This is the angular index.html file]

[image: This is the controller having the Service]